# Global `beforeEach` in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine to write tests.

I have several test files, each file has a `beforeEach`, but they are exactly the same.

How do I provide a **global** `beforeEach` for them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put it in your `spec_helper.js` file and it should work fine.

Comment: Does this `spec_helper.js` will be recognized by jasmine automatically?

Comment: Not automatically - we added ours to the `helpers` directory.

Comment: Do you mean, we should `require('./spec_helper')` in each of our test files?

Comment: It's included in our `jasmine.yml` file, so we don't have to require it in every test.

Comment: @Blacksonic exact code for which? the actual beforeEach, or just what's in jasmine.yml?

Comment: finally solved, found out that beforEach is also declared globally

Answer (score 83):

x1a4's answer confused me. This may be more clear:

When you declare a `beforeEach` function **outside** all `describe` blocks, it will trigger before each test (so before each `it`). It does not matter if you declare the `beforeEach` before or after your `describe` blocks.

You can include this in any specfile included in your test run—including in a file all on its own, hence the concept of a spec helper file that might contain just your global `beforeEach` declaration.

[It's not mentioned in the documentation.](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown)

```
// Example: 

beforeEach(function() {
    localStorage.clear();
});

describe('My tests', function() {
    describe('Test localstorage', function() {

        it('Adds an item to localStorage', function() {
            localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
            expect(localStorage.getItem('foo')).toBe('bar');
        });

        it('Is now empty because our beforeEach cleared localStorage', function() {
            expect(localStorage.getItem('foo')).toBe(null);
        });

    });
});
```