# How to reuse beforeEach/afterEach in Jasmine JS?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, dry

When writing tests with JasmineJS I have many tests that have similar beforeEach/afterEach code.

Is there a way to implement an inheritance model using JasmineJS test suites?

I can group all tests in a single `describe` but in this case I will end with a single HUGE JS file containing all tests.

I would like to split the tests for each page.

Here is an example:

```
describe('Services Page', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        login_as_admin()
    })

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser().navigateTo('/services')
    })

    if('Some test for services page', function() {})

    afterEach(function() {
        logout()
    })

})


describe('Administrators Page', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        login_as_admin()
    })

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser().navigateTo('/administrators')
    })

    if('Some test for administrators page', function() {})

    afterEach(function() {
        logout()
    })

})
```

Comment: will every page have `login_as_admin()` and `logout()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global \`beforeEach\` in jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560716/global-beforeeach-in-jasmine)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think this is partially examined [in this blog post](http://pivotallabs.com/drying-up-jasmine-specs-with-shared-behavior/) and also [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6440097/511069) but i'm adding an adapted answer for your example:

Reusable code:

```
function sharedSetup(startPage) {
    beforeEach(function() {
        login_as_admin();
        browser().navigateTo(startPage);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        logout();
    });
};
```

How to use it:

```
describe('Services Page', function() {
    sharedSetup('/services');

    it('Some test for services page', function() {});
});

describe('Administrators Page', function() {
    sharedSetup('/administrators');

    it('Some test for administrators page', function() {});
});
```

Comment: The updated link for the blog post is [here](https://tanzu.vmware.com/content/blog/drying-up-jasmine-specs-with-shared-behavior) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20141005190338/http://pivotallabs.com/drying-up-jasmine-specs-with-shared-behavior/) an old version with the missing code snippets.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to do this for all your suites, you can register a `beforeEach` or `afterEach` function in the `topSuite`:

```
jasmine.getEnv().topSuite().beforeEach({fn: function() {
   //log in as admin
}});
```

If you only want to apply it on some suites, you can work with sub-suites:

```
describe("as_admin", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    //log in as admin
  });

  describe('Services Page',function() {...});
  describe('Administrators Page',function() {...});

}
```

Comment: I think it is also possible to use:

jasmine.getEnv().beforeEach(function () {
//log in as admin
});

based on tests included in changes here: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/811

Comment: Looks like it's important to call `done()` callback in `beforeEach` as it hangs without it.

Answer (score 5):

Jasmine does allow you to put `beforeEach` and `afterEach` outside of a `describe` call. In this way you can have setup and teardown that is global for all of your specs. Your `logout()` call seems like it might be a good candidate for global teardown, and if all of your specs login as an admin, you could move that out to global scope as well.

For things that are used in some, but not all, specs, having a method like your `login_as_admin()` seems like the best way to consolidate that logic in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: ([Pivotal Labs Blog:Davis W. Frank](http://pivotallabs.com/drying-up-jasmine-specs-with-shared-behavior/))

He describes collecting shared functionality in a function that is called with parameters for the different individual suites.  Calling this function within each suite will execute the common setup/configuration.

As to splitting tests across files; the file with the shared function can either be included within each page with a `<script>` tag if the tests are browser based, or by a `require(...)` near the top if the tests are node based.  You can then run the tests independently but using that shared setup which is defined only once.

Answer (score 0):

Found [in the issues](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1914#issuecomment-841427421).

> So in 3.7.0 `afterEach` along with other methods got moved out of `Env` namespace and into Globals.
>
> the call in *test.ts* should be now:
>
> `afterEach(() => {});`
>
> that's it.