# Jasmine helpers in Protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor

Jasmine offers way to run helper files before specs using its [`helpers` option](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/node.html#section-9). I wanted to use a helper file to add a global beforeEach call, so all tests run this before they are started. But I somehow fail to find the way to do this using protractor (that uses Jasmine).

How can I add helpers option for jasmine in Protractor. Can I somewhere specify Jasmine's options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/node.html#section-9), `helpers` scripts are executed before the specs. In protractor, this is what `onPrepare()` function is responsible for. Here is a [sample `onPrepare()` function](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js#L18) that logs into the application before any specs were executed.

Also, here is a relevant topic on the subject of sharing the `beforeEach()` setup across specs:

- [How to reuse beforeEach/afterEach in Jasmine JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317839/how-to-reuse-beforeeach-aftereach-in-jasmine-js)