# Call another protractor test from another test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I would like to know if it is possible to call a protractor test inside another protractor. For exemple :

```
 it('should go on edit profile', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:9100/#/');
    browser.setLocation('profile');
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(actualUrl) {
        if (actualUrl.indexOf("/login") > 0) {
            require('../login/login.js');
            // call test of login.js ???
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for yours answers ! :)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted most convenient way is to reuse code through [page objects](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md), just wrap the shared functionality in a `function` like I explain at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24046016/511069

Regarding [what to do](https://gist.github.com/thiagofelix/a5132f2c97f55518b1ed#file-example_pages_spec-js) after `require` is related to [NodeJS modules](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/), see for example `var AngularPage = require('../pages/angular.page.js');` at [thoughtworks blog post](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out !