# Allure reports are not generated in Protractor

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor, allure

I included the below code in my `conf.js` file but the Allure reports are not getting generated.

```
onPrepare : function() {
    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new AllureReporter({
            allureReport : {
                resultsDir : 'allure-results'
            }
        })
    );

    jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function(done) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
            allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function() {
                return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
            }, 'image/png')();
            done();
        })
    });
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.
Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: Let's debug a little bit. What if you put everything you have under `jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function(done) {` and move it into an `afterEach` block in one of your tests - do you see the report generated after the test run? Thanks.

Comment: I did it and tried. It gives the error as "ReferenceError: allure is not defined" and all the tests are failed.

Comment: I did it and tried. It gives the error as "A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow."

Included the following code in my test file.afterEach(function(done) {
   var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
   allureReport : {
    resultsDir : 'allure-results'
   }
  }))
  });

Answer (score 1):

Register a [top suite after each function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30210205/771848):

```
onPrepare : function() {
    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    var reporter = new AllureReporter({
        allureReport : {
            resultsDir : 'allure-results'
        }
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

    jasmine.getEnv().topSuite().afterEach({fn: function() {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
            allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function() {
                return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
            }, 'image/png')();
        })
    }});
}
```

Not tested.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your reply. But I has to make a small change to make it work. Instead of "reporter.createAttachment('Screenshot', function() {", I had to change it as "allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function() {"