# protractor-html-screenshot-reporter does not work

Tags: html, protractor, report, screenshot

I have done everything as written on https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter, but no HTML or screenshots are saved to folder.

I've installed protractor-html-screenshot-reporter with command:

```
npm install protractor-html-screenshot-reporter --save-dev
```

I have then done npm init and saved package.json file, which contains:

```
 ...
 "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.0",
    "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter": "0.0.21"
  },
 ...
```

I can also see protractor-html-screenshot-reporter in **/node_modules/** folder.

In config file I have the following:

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

exports.config = {
    ...

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
        onComplete: null,
        isVerbose: false,
        includeStackTrace: false,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 1000000,
        print: function() {}

    },

    onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            baseDirectory: '../reports/screenshots',
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            docTitle: 'Desk test report',
            docName: 'desk_report.html',
            preserveDirectory: true
        }));
   }
}
```

Now when I run protractor conf.js I don't see any /reports/screenshots folder, HTML report or screenshot created. Help please!

Comment: Hey did my answer helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jasmine allure Reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-allure-reporter) is better for `reports` and `screenshots`

Below is the code for it:

```
//conf.js

exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',  
 jasmineNodeOpts: {
  showColors: true,
  includeStackTrace: true,
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 144000000
 },
directConnect: true,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['/**/Tests/**/*test.js'],
capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome' },

 onPrepare: function () {
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15000);
    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
        allureReport: {
            resultsDir: 'allure-results'
        }
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function (done) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
            allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                return new Buffer(png, 'base64');
            }, 'image/png')();
            done();
        });
      });
      }
```

I Hope this solves your problem. Visit the Link for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have installed it, but the problem I get is the same as with protractor-html-screenshot-reporter, meaning that no XML or screenshot is created. What bothers me that no error is reported once conf.js file is started, even if I change `var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');` to `var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allureX-reporter');`.

Comment: I am using it daily brother. It should work. Can you send share your test file also along with conf.js .  A folder named 'allure-results' must be created or else change resultDir to D:/Allure-results.

Comment: Lucky you and unlucky me ;) I have also used the full path, like `var AllureReporter = require('/home/lxuser/node_modules/jasmine-allure-reporter');` with no changes. Is there also something I should write in my test spec file? I'm using Linux.

Comment: Jasmine-allureX-reporter ? I am having Jasmine-allure-reporter. Please check.

Comment: I copy pasted, sorry about that. I do have `var AllureReporter = require('/home/lxuser/node_modules/jasmine-allure-reporter')‌​;` and no allure-results folder is created along with XML and screenshots.

Comment: One more thing, just to confirm, jasmine2 frameworks should be set in conf.js file, right?

Comment: I'm saying as you have used absolute path for this , use the same for you resultdirectory under onprepare method i.e. resultsDir : ' your absolute path/ allure-results' . I hope I'm clear

Comment: Yes put jasmine2 as well

Comment: Still nothing. I have used absolute paths with no avail: `var AllureReporter = require('/home/lxuser/node_modules/jasmine-allure-reporter');var reporter = new AllureReporter({
  allureReport:{
   resultsDir: '/home/lxuser/allure-results'
   }   
  });
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
 
  jasmine.getEnv().topSuite().afterEach({fn: function(){
         browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
           reporter.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
              return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
          }, 'image/png')();
          
         })
      }});`

Comment: I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967224/allure-reports-are-not-generated-in-protractor.

Comment: Let me have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137067/discussion-between-kishan-patel-and-jurijk).