# mochaOpts require file in protractor config

Tags: typescript, protractor, mocha.js

I want to add a helper file for a global `afterEach` in my protractor conf file. But how do i load the file? I have tried like, but it does not work.

conf.ts

```
 mochaOpts: {
            file: './hooks.js',
            }
 }
```

hooks.ts

```
afterEach(async () => {
  console.log('---global after each');
});
```

Comment: not sure how mocha works but try `file: require('./hooks.js'),`

Comment: Thanks, that worked to load the file. However I get error `afterEach is not defined`. So i guess the approach im using is not possible? How else would i get this global hook to run after every test spec, without having to include it in each test spec?

Answer (score 0):

So first problem is solved by requesting the file this way

```
file: require('./hooks.js')
```

For you next question see the discussion here for Jasmine [How to reuse beforeEach/afterEach in Jasmine JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317839/how-to-reuse-beforeeach-aftereach-in-jasmine-js) I'm sure it's possible to do similar in Mocha