# Karma Jasmine global object is not reinitialized on beforeEach causing tests to fail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

One of my angular modules has the following in its config:

```
angular.module('feature').config(function () {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('expressioneditor', {});
});
```

`CKEDITOR` is a global object that is added via `<script>` tag to the page. As I understand, `Karma` reinitializes angular application for each `beforeEach` block, while the global `CKEDITOR` object remains the same. This reinitialization process makes `config` being called multiple times, and this code `CKEDITOR.plugins.add('expressioneditor', {});` is also executed multiple times. The problem is that `CKEDITOR.plugins.add` throws an error if an attempt is made to add a plugin with the same name multiple times, so my tests fail. This problem doesn't exist in runtime environment, since `config` functions are run only once during angular's initialization stage.

My question is what is the common approach to reinitialization of global environment before each test? For my particular case, I can add a check for the existence of a plugin before adding it, but this question is about the general approach.

Comment: Does your `CKEDITOR.plugins` has a remove Method?. The ideal approach is to not share state in between tests making every test unique and isolated from each other. So IMO you should remove that plugin inside a jasmine `afterEach` block. See http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown

Comment: Thanks, but I'd have to do that in every test spec _even if the CKEDITOR is not used in this spec_, because this spec may require angular modules that  call `CKEDITOR.plugins.add` function in a `config` block. Maybe there's an option to somehow put the clearing logic into one shared file with `afterEach` block, that is executed for each test spec?

Comment: Yes I think you can do that. For instance. You put test specs inside a `describe` block. but if you write a `beforeEach` or an `afterEach` block outside a `describe` block, what it will do is that the code inside of them will be executed "globally" for each test. Probably checking the existence of the plugin before attempting to remove it does not sound that bad at all inside that global `afterEach` block. See this great answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25053685/2970209. I always reference a `testUtil.js` to do that stuff in my tests when needed

Comment: @CesarAlvarado, thanks a lot, I'll take a look

Comment: @CesarAlvarado, _I always reference a testUtil.js to do that stuff_ - how do you reference it?

Comment: I create a .js file in which I put that global logic and reference it inside the karma.conf.js before the actual spec files. For example, the files property of my projects looks like this:

    `files: [  'test/helpers/testUtil.js', 'app/**/*.js' ]`

Comment: yeah, that's a way to go. you can post the summary as an answer and I'll accept it